# Recover Deleted Git Repository from Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, git

I am stuck here and in extreme need to expert advise

I have created an Android project in Eclipse and was in the process of creating a git repository for it using EGit.

I have gone through the normal process of creating a repo in Eclipse: right-click project -> Team -> Share Project

I gave the repo a name and hit continue to create it.

The progress bar started flashing but in the middle i got a problem creating the repo. I do not remember what the issue was but i decided to delete that repo and start from scratch.

So i went to Git Repositories in Eclipse and hit delete repo. I checked the box that says delete existing files in the repo. And unfortunately, the whole Android project was deleted from Eclipse :(

i was not aware that by creating a repo the original files will be copied over to the repo folder and removed from the workspace :'(

Does any one know an approach to recover that deleted repo/project?

Many thanks

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, deleted project so there is no "Recover from local history" button to click, and no local windows history, but you can do a manual recover from history.
I tried this solution in Eclipse Oxygen/Windows 10,
First of all,  eclipse store history file at here,

```
(workspace)/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.history/
```

and there is a lot of file with long name like this '006de3225c86001811b7ff2e93138537', that's the history file eclipse using to recover, you can search the text inside those file for the package name of the deleted project, then you can pick the latest one, copy past it to the new project location, renaming them to the correct file name. This approach is complex, but works for me.

Answer (score 2):

In eclipse there is an option for projects. Right of project and see : "Recover from local history". This should help you

Comment: The thing is the project is completely deleted from the Projects list in eclipse... :(

Comment: Legend!! Thank you so much for sharing this

Answer (score 0):

If you deleted your git repository permanently and it is showing that there is no project or file on eclipse window .
Then go to your current workspace of eclipse and search these file name there,  you got all of your file there and you can see every folder and files of that project.
The workspace of eclipse is in C:/User/name/workspace/current_workspace_name/project_name